# Customize the hippo cms

Tags: java, content-management-system, hippocms

Can we customize the bloomreach cms? For eg: I have a user with role branch-manager and i want to give user management functionality but only for 2 or 3 users and not all users. Or any such custom features like sat changr the background color that we can implement on cms?  Please help ne with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible. You'd have to customize the security such that the user has admin privileges but can only see a limited set of users. You'd need a custom security domain that grants read write privileges on the specific users. You should be able to split the users into separate folders on the repository level, but that doesn't exist in the UI. So setting up such a domain may be tricky.

See the documentation on security:

https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/library/concepts/security/authorization-model-concepts.html

And some walkthroughs on common cases
https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/library/concepts/security/how-to.html

The cms UI is written in wicket. You can hook into this to add your own fucntionality. You have a very limited ability to customize the cms. For example, in the document editor. Mostly though you are stuck with it looking as it does.

https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/library/concepts/plugins/plugin-development.html

https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/library/concepts/editor-interface/tweak-the-css-of-the-cms.html

Comment: Thanks Jasper. Maybe i can avail the souce code of the cms and change the logic there. How does it sound?